# GitLab MR title checking automation

Tags: gitlab

I use GitLab, and I've got the rules MRs need to satisfy to.

How can I automate GitLab MR title checking? (maybe with pipelines?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[At the moment](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16080) there is no internal GitLab feature for this.

One of the possible solutions is to create [merge request pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html) with a job which will get merge request title via `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE` [predefined variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#predefined-variables-for-merge-request-pipelines) and do the validation. Possible job definition:

```
validate-mr:
  image: your/image/url
  script:
    - echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE
    # do title validation here 
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
```

`rules` block is making job to run only on merge request pipelines.